# How to implement Spring integration with cxf endpoint

Tags: spring-integration

We have existing endpoint (cxf:cxfEndpoint), Now we have to invoke spring integration application from this existing endpoint, I found some examples using jaxws endpoint, but unable to find using cxfendpoint. Could you please help me by providing some reference or example code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CXF (we have Spring WS instead), but I believe the concept is like to wrap some POJO method call to that endpoint.

Spring Integration provide a `@MessagingGateway` abstraction with an interface marked with some annotations to send messages to the channel when a method on this interface is called.

So, on one side you configure such a gateway for Spring Integration and on the other side you use an instance (bean) of this interface to wrap into CXF endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I used camel with cxf in spring project like this. maybe it's useful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
   xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing"
   xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
   xmlns:soap="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap"
   xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/ws/addressing.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/soap http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/soap.xsd
                        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
                        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">



<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="CXFTest" address="/javainuse/learn"
                 endpointName="a:SOATestEndpoint" serviceName="a:SOATestEndpointService"
                 serviceClass="com.javainuse.SOATestEndpoint"
                 xmlns:a ="http://javainuse.com">
    <cxf:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding mtomEnabled="false" version="1.2" />
    </cxf:binding>

    <cxf:features>
        <wsa:addressing  xmlns:wsa="http://cxf.apache.org/ws/addressing"/>
    </cxf:features>

</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```